# Clojurescript/OM persist app-state through refresh

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, om

I followed the basic tutorial on [OM's github](https://github.com/omcljs/om) [Basic Tutorial](https://github.com/omcljs/om/wiki/Basic-Tutorial) which is a simple form which enables the array of contacts stored within the app state to be modified however, these modifications are 'reset' upon page refresh.

If i remove 3 people from the current `app-state` and refresh, these 3 people will be present in the `app-state` again.

The code is the same as the tutorial, but ill post it anyway:

```
(ns ^:figwheel-always om-tut.core
  (:require-macros [cljs.core.async.macros :refer [go]])
  (:require [om.core :as om :include-macros true]
            [om.dom :as dom :include-macros true]
            [cljs.core.async :refer [put! chan <!]]
            [clojure.data :as data]
            [clojure.string :as string]))

(enable-console-print!)

(println "Edits to this text should show up in your developer console.")

;; define your app data so that it doesn't get over-written on reload

(defonce app-state
  (atom
    {:contacts
     [{:first "Ben" :last "Bitdiddle" :email "benb@mit.edu"}
      {:first "Alyssa" :middle-initial "P" :last "Hacker" :email "aphacker@mit.edu"}
      {:first "Eva" :middle "Lu" :last "Ator" :email "eval@mit.edu"}
      {:first "Louis" :last "Reasoner" :email "prolog@mit.edu"}
      {:first "Cy" :middle-initial "D" :last "Effect" :email "bugs@mit.edu"}
      {:first "Lem" :middle-initial "E" :last "Tweakit" :email "morebugs@mit.edu"}]}))

(defn middle-name [{:keys [middle middle-initial]}]
  (cond
    middle (str " " middle)
    middle-initial (str " " middle-initial ".")))

(defn display-name [{:keys [first last] :as contact}]
  (str last ", " first (middle-name contact)))

(defn contact-view [contact owner]
  (reify
    om/IRenderState
    (render-state [this {:keys [delete]}]
      (dom/li nil
        (dom/span nil (display-name contact))
        (dom/button #js {:onClick (fn [e] (put! delete @contact))} "Delete")))))

(defn handle-change [e owner {:keys [text]}]
   (let [value (.. e -target -value)]
     (if-not (re-find #"[0-9]" value)
       (om/set-state! owner :text value)
       (om/set-state! owner :text text))))


(defn parse-contact [contact-str]
  (let [[first middle last :as parts] (string/split contact-str #"\s+")
        [first last middle] (if (nil? last) [first middle] [first last middle])
        middle (when middle (string/replace middle "." ""))
        c (if middle (count middle) 0)]
    (when (>= (count parts) 2)
      (cond-> {:first first :last last}
        (== c 1) (assoc :middle-initial middle)
        (>= c 2) (assoc :middle middle)))))

(defn add-contact [data owner]
  (let [new-contact (-> (om/get-node owner "new-contact")
                        .-value
                        parse-contact)]
    (when new-contact
      (om/transact! data :contacts #(conj % new-contact))
      (om/set-state! owner :text ""))))

(defn contacts-view [data owner]
  (reify
    om/IInitState
    (init-state [_]
      {:delete (chan)
       :text ""})
    om/IWillMount
    (will-mount [_]
      (let [delete (om/get-state owner :delete)]
        (go (loop []
              (let [contact (<! delete)]
                (om/transact! data :contacts
                  (fn [xs] (vec (remove #(= contact %) xs))))
                (recur))))))
    om/IRenderState
    (render-state [this state]
      (dom/div nil
        (dom/h2 nil "Contact list")
        (apply dom/ul nil
          (om/build-all contact-view (:contacts data)
            {:init-state state}))
        (dom/div nil
          (dom/input
            #js {:type "text" :ref "new-contact" :value (:text state)
                 :onChange #(handle-change % owner state)})
          (dom/button #js {:onClick #(add-contact data owner)} "Add contact"))))))


(om/root contacts-view app-state
  {:target (. js/document (getElementById "contacts"))})


(defn on-js-reload []
  ;; optionally touch your app-state to force rerendering depending on
  ;; your application
  ;; (swap! app-state update-in [:__figwheel_counter] inc)
)
```

Comment: by refresh you mean refresh the whole page from the browser? that tutorial is a client-side application, all the modifications and state you perform on the app is on the browser, if you refresh all state is lost. happens for any javascript app

Comment: @GuillermoWinkler Thank you! wasnt sure if this was preventable or not.

Comment: You could look at using https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel. It will do live reloading of your ClojureScript code. It means your code will be reloaded when it changes and you don't have to refresh the browser. BUT anything in a `defonce` won't be reloaded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data on the client has to either be persisted on the server or in local storage.  Refreshing the browser/reloading the browser is the same as starting from scratch.  So, any data you had is gone, unless you persisted it.